# How to trigger an event after 30 seconds has passed in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm writing a game, and as a part of the game the protagonists will be killed if they cannot escape a room in 30 seconds. Is there a mechanism that allows me to do this in Django? My current solution is to

```
InformProtagonists("Escape in 30 seconds!")
time.sleep(30);
if protagonists in room:
  NotifyProtagonists("YOU DIE");
```

But I'm wondering whether there's a better approach.

Comment: What do you mean *"in Django"*? You could run a JS timer on the client side.

Comment: It's a multiplayer game. One person will trigger the timer, and it will affect everyone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import threading
timer = threading.Timer(30.0, KillPlayers, [request, player])
timer.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use django just for the backend (pulling data from DB with an api and submitting data back if needed).

And handle the rest with javascript and something like [react](https://facebook.github.io/react/) and [redux](http://redux.js.org/).

django isn't really built for displaying stuff.

Comment: :) mixing up my answers there. Wanted to say he should do it in a different language,

Comment: You're right that django (and python in this case) is not the right tool for the problem at hand, but you should clarify that in your answer. I think the `switch` code sample isn't necessary here.

Comment: Edited my answer per your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Django is a server-side web framework. You interact with it through network requests and responses. It's not really well suited for any part of real-time game development beyond managing your backend data.

You probably just need to look at building your game with some front-end javascript.

Comment: What you'll probably want to do, then, is have your players send data back to the server that needs to be shared with other players. One really good way to do that is to use something like [socket.io](http://socket.io/) on the frontend. You may find that Django isn't as good of a fit for the backend as something like Node.JS, but that's another matter. :)